# Padding a quantum circuit to increase the amplitude by a constant

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, complexity-theory

Let us be given the description of a quantum circuit $\mathsf{Q}$, acting on $n$ qubits, such that

\begin{equation}
\langle 0^n|\mathsf{Q}|0^n\rangle  = \frac{\#0_f - \#1_f}{\sqrt{2^n}},
\end{equation}
for some Boolean function $f : \{0, 1\}^n \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$, where $\#0_f$ and $\#1_f$ are the number of inputs for which $f$ evaluates to $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Let's say one could find a description of $f$ when given a description for $\mathsf{Q}$. Now, is there a way to efficiently construct the circuit $\mathsf{Q_k}$ such that the amplitudes of $\mathsf{Q_k}$ look like
\begin{equation}
\frac{\#0_f - \#1_f~+k}{\sqrt{2^n}},
\end{equation}
for some constant integer $k$?

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.1674) (page $10$), it is mentioned that this is what is termed a "padding argument," and the paper seems to contend that this can be done by using "$k$ additional inputs." But it wasn't immediately clear to me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the paper that above question references, it is assumed that we are given a classical circuit $C$ which computes the function $f: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and an another classical algorithm which takes $C$ as the input and outputs a diagonal quantum circuit $Q$ which uses $\mathrm{T} = $ poly$(n,|C|)$ qubits such that

\begin{align}
\langle 0^n|Q|0^n\rangle = \frac{\#0_f - \#1_f}{2^T}
\end{align}

The author of the paper claims that you can modify the circuit $C$, not $Q$, by adding $k$ additional input (by the increasing the domain size by $k$, not the number of input bits) to make a new circuit $C[k]$ such that $C(x) = 1$ for $x$ in the newly added domain. Now you can pass this new circuit to the classical algorithm which converts into a quantum circuit $Q_k$ as the question asks.

Comment: How can you modify $C$ without adding extra input bits?

Comment: In general, you do need to add extra bits to modify the circuit $C$.

Comment: Could you provide a sketch of how in your answer?